# Problema al momento de crear un volumen con docker y ejecutar un archivo

Tags: python-3.x, docker, docker-compose

Tengo una aplicación en python y quiero crear un nuevo volumen para almacenar los datos de la aplicación

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: app
    container_name: app
    #volumes:
      #- "C:\\Users\\test\\Documents\\volumenes_docker\\fija\\telefonia:/usr/src/app"
```

```
FROM python:3.10

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

#RUN CD build

CMD ["python", "build/main.py"]
```

si comento las líneas de volumen funciona perfectamente si las agrego aparece el siguiente error: **python: can't open file '/usr/src/app/build/main.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory**

Cuál sería el error o como se debería de agregar el volumen ?